# rqt-image-view datatype mismatch

Tags: gazebo, ros-kinetic, ardrone

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the rqt_image_view via command below:

```
rosrun rqt_image_view rqt_image_view
```

I have received an error:

```
[ERROR] [1517309067.634525993, 814.130000000]: Client [/gazebo] wants topic /ardrone/bottom/image_raw to have datatype/md5sum [sensor_msgs/Image/060021388200f6f0f447d0fcd9c64743], but our version has [geometry_msgs/Point/4a842b65f413084dc2b10fb484ea7f17]. Dropping connection.
```

I has something to do with data type mismatch but I am not sure how I should resolve it. Any workaround?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/281222/rqt-image-view-datatype-mismatch/) by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1053 on 2018-01-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found out that after reinstalling the ROS solves the issue by running the following command along with setting up the appropriate ROS environment variables:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-desktop-full
```

---

Originally posted by [alfa_80](https://answers.ros.org/users/121/alfa_80/) with karma: 1053 on 2018-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1